# How to give 2 characters for "delimiter" using csv module?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to generate the csv with delimiter '@|@' but, I couldn't achieve through below code.

```
import csv
ifile  = open('test.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
ofile  = open('ttest.csv', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='|', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)
ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

While running, It has thrown below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "csvfile.py", line 6, in <module>
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='@|@', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: replace('@|@', '|') or to something that does not contain in your string

Comment: `'@|@'` looks like a three character delimiter...and the code in the traceback doesn't match the code in your snippet.

Answer (score 2):

In csv [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter) they say

> A one-character string used to separate fields. It defaults to ','.

So you can do this as an alternative.

```
csv.reader((line.replace('@|@', '|') for line in ifile), delimiter='|')
```

So the complete code is,

```
import csv
ifile  = open('test.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader((line.replace('@|@', '|') for line in ifile), delimiter='|')
ofile  = open('ttest.csv', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='|', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)
ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The *csvfile* argument to the `csv.writer` constructor only has to be a "file-like object". This means you could supply an instance of your own class which changes a single character into one with two or more characters (but which otherwise acts like a open output file object).

Here's what I mean:

```
import csv

class CSV_Translater(object):
    """ Output file-like object that translates characters. """
    def __init__(self, f, old, new):
        self.f = f
        self.old = old
        self.new = new
    def write(self, s):
        self.f.write(s.replace(self.old, self.new))
    def close(self):
        self.f.close()
    def flush(self):
        self.f.flush()

with open('in_test.csv', "rb") as ifile:
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    with open('out_test.csv', "wb") as ofile:
        translater = CSV_Translater(ofile, '|', '@|@')
        writer = csv.writer(translater, delimiter='|', quotechar='"',
                            quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```